# onActivityResult's intent.getPath() doesn't give me the correct filename

Tags: android, file

I am trying to fetch a file this way:

```
final Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    String[] mimetypes = {"application/pdf"};
    chooseFileIntent.setType("*/*");
    chooseFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    if (chooseFileIntent.resolveActivity(activity
                        .getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        chooseFileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
        activity.startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, Uploader.PDF);
    }
```

Then in `onActivityResult` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

According to many threads I'm supposed to fetch the file name from the intent with `data.getData().getPath()`, the file name I'm expecting is *my_file.pdf*, but instead I'm getting this :

> /document/acc=1;doc=28

So what to do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch a file

Not with that code. That code is asking the user to pick a piece of content. This may or may not be a file.

> According to many threads I'm supposed to fetch the file name from the intent with data.getData().getPath()

That was never correct, though it tended to work on older versions of Android.

> So what to do?

Well, that depends.

<strike>If you wish to only accept files, integrate [a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) instead of using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.</strike> (**UPDATE 2019-04-06**: since Android Q is banning most filesystem access, this solution is no longer practical)

If you are willing to allow the user to pick a piece of content using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, please understand that it does not have to be a file and it does not have to have something that resembles a filename. The closest that you will get:

- If `getScheme()` of the `Uri` returns `file`, your original algorithm will work
- If `getScheme()` of the `Uri` returns `content`, use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to create a `DocumentFile`, then call `getName()` on that `DocumentFile` — this should return a "display name" which should be recognizable to the user

Comment: Really great and complete answer! Thank you very much, `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` did the trick :)

Comment: @CommonsWare, How to get the file path using DocumentFile ?

Comment: @Amila You don't. You open an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` in the `DocumentFile`, and you consume the content that way.

Comment: it may not work always ! check my solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104787/3141844

Answer (score 0):

To get the real name and to avoid getting a name that looks like "image: 4431" or even just a number, you can write code as recommended by CommonsWare.

The following is an example of a code that selects a single pdf file, prints its name and path to the log, and then sends the file by email using its uri.

```
private static final int FILEPICKER_RESULT_CODE = 1;
private static final int SEND_EMAIL_RESULT_CODE = 2;
private Uri fileUri;

private void chooseFile() {
    Intent fileChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    fileChooser.setType("application/pdf");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileChooser, "Choose one pdf file"), FILEPICKER_RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == FILEPICKER_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            fileUri = data != null ? data.getData() : null;
            if (fileUri != null) {
                DocumentFile d = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, fileUri);
                if (d != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "file name: " + d.getName());
                    Log.d("TAG", "file path: " + d.getUri().getPath());
                    sendEmail(fileUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendEmail(Uri path) {
    String email = "example@gmail.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "PDF file");
    String[] to = { email };
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the pdf file...");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."), SEND_EMAIL_RESULT_CODE);
}
```

hope it helps.