# getRealPathFromURI not working anymore

Tags: android, uri

I've had this code in my app for a few years now and it stopped working on new versions on Android.  Haven't programmed in years so I'm rusty.  Can someone please point to a quick fix to check api/sdk levels?

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
        }
```

Comment: See also [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510584/onactivityresults-intent-getpath-doesnt-give-me-the-correct-filename).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code written in Java. It handles all the cases with the different SDK versions. I didn't own all the code below, I copied some of it from somewhere a years ago. I don't know and cannot reference it right now. But hey, it works

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626)

```
public class RealPathUtil {

public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    String realPath;
    // SDK < API11
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
    else {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
    }
    return realPath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = 0;
    String result = "";
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri     The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

Comment: i tried this and get error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at library.RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(RealPathUtil.java:127)
                                                                   at library.RealPathUtil.getRealPath(RealPathUtil.java:28)