# _data column not available at FileProvider uri

Tags: android, file, path, uri, android-contentresolver

I'm using the FileProvider pattern for creating content:// uri to files, with the

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.provider", file)
```

function. I have the manifest, provider_paths and everything set the standard way,  It creates an uri like `content://com.myapp.provider/external_files/music/mysong.mp3`.

My issue is that if I try getting the real file path in another app, it doesn't work as the `_data` column doesn't exist (to be specific the error in logs is `E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0 columns.`). For fetching the real path I'm using the also pretty much standard function

```
final String column = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA;
final String[] projection = { column  };
try {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
```

If I use a different app for sharing the same file it generates an uri like `content://com.otherapp.provider/external_files/music/mysong.mp3`, from which I can already retrieve the real file path. Any ideas what do I have to do to make sure that my app properly inserts the given uri to ContentResolver? Manual `contentResolver.insert(...)` functions are not allowed. I've tried different versions of provider_paths.xml and granting all possible read/write permissions to the given uri, but I could never retrieve the real path.

The uri itself generated by me works fine as I can read the file or play the song, my issue is just that I cannot retrieve the real file path that I need.

Thanks

Comment: Yet another... There is no proper way to get "real file path", end of story. Also you DON'T NEED IT.

Answer (score 5):

> My issue is that if I try getting the real file path in another app

The other app should not be trying to do this.

> For fetching the real path I'm using the also pretty much standard function

That works for very few `Uri` values.

> If I use a different app for sharing the same file it generates an uri like content://com.otherapp.provider/external_files/music/mysong.mp3, from which I can already retrieve the real file path.

That is not guaranteed.

> Any ideas what do I have to do to make sure that my app properly inserts the given uri to ContentResolver?

You don't. You fix the client app, which should not be attempting to get a "real file path" from a `Uri`.

> my issue is just that I cannot retrieve the real file path that I need.

Instead, for a `Uri` with a `content` scheme:

Step #1: Get a `ContentResolver`, by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context` (e.g., an activity)

Step #2: Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on that content

Step #3: Consume the content via that `InputStream`

If you are using some third-party library that can only work with files, copy the data from that `InputStream` to some `FileOutputStream`, then use the resulting file with that library.

This way, no matter where the content is coming from (a file that you could access, a file that you cannot access, a `BLOB` column in a database, etc.), you will have code that works.

See also:

- [Getting the Absolute File Path from Content URI for searched images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870825/getting-the-absolute-file-path-from-content-uri-for-searched-images)
- [onActivityResult's intent.getPath() doesn't give me the correct filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510584/onactivityresults-intent-getpath-doesnt-give-me-the-correct-filename)
- [Android - Get real path of a .txt file selected from the file explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer)

Comment: I use a third-party image processing library that only works with paths to files and heavily depends on the file extension to help it decode said file. I can do as you suggest and create a new file from the stream but i need the file extension or perhaps full filename and extension of the original file, is there anyway this can get passed via the URI?

Comment: @Asiimwe: No. There is no requirement for the `Uri` to point to anything that might have ever been a file anywhere. You can get a MIME type, and you can try to use `MimeTypeMap` to derive a file extension, but there is no guarantee that the MIME type reported for that `Uri` is known to `MimeTypeMap`. You can get a "display name", but there is no requirement that it is a filename. If you absolutely need a file, [use a file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) that only works with the filesystem, instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc.