# File path in real device shows wrong path

Tags: android, filepath, filechooser, android-afilechooser

In my class, I use the following method to get the file path, **but it works only on the emulator; why?**

My problem is with the real device (Samsung Galaxy j5):

1. The files in the internal hard:**Encounter with Exception.**
2. The files in the external hard: **return a null path.**

How can I fix this problem? The problem is in which part of my code.

UploaderActivity :

```
public class UploaderActictivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG ="MyPath" ;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE =10052 ;
Uri URI =null ;
private Button button;
private String path;
TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton,BrowsButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
ImageView imNotify;
JustifiedTextView js;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploader);
    js=findViewById(R.id.textDes);
    js.setText( getResources().getString(des) + "\n" +
                getResources().getString(des1)+ "\n" +
                getResources().getString(des2)+ "\n" +
                getResources().getString(des3));

    uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.upload);
    BrowsButton = findViewById(R.id.browse);
    BrowsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    messageText =findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    imNotify =findViewById(R.id.notify);
    String msg=messageText.getText().toString();

    if(msg.isEmpty()){
        messageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imNotify.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==BrowsButton) {
        showFileChooser();

    }

    if(v==uploadButton) {

        //upload to site
        if(path != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploaderActictivity.this, "", "آپلود فایل، لطفاً صبر کنید...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            imNotify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            messageText.setText("در حال آپلود فایل...");
                        }
                    });


                    uploadFile(path);


                }
            }).start();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this,"ابتدا یک فایل انتخاب کنید!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


private void showFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("*/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"انتخاب فایل..."),REQUEST_CODE);

}



@Override
protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data == null) {
                //no data present
                return;
            }

            Uri currFileURI = data.getData();
            path = FilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(),currFileURI);

            if(path != null && !path.equals("") ){
                imNotify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected File Path:" + path);

                messageText.setText(path);



            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"شما قادر به آپلود محتوای فایل نیستید!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}



public int uploadFile(final String path) {


    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final int UserID =prefs.getInt("UserID", 0);


    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(path);

    String[] parts = path.split("/");
    final String fileName = UserID + "_" + parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +path);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("محتوایی در این مسیر وجود ندارد!"
                        +path);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {


            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(AppConfig.upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);



            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "فايل مورد نظر آپلود شد." +
                                "\n" + getResources().getString(DescriptionForUpload)
                                ;
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this, "آپلود فايل کامل شد.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }



            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this, "مشکلی رخ داده است!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(UploaderActictivity.this, "مشکلی رخ داده است!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

FilePath class:

```
public class FilePath {


public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {


            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + split[1];
                }
            }
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                        Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }

    return null;
}


public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}


public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post exception log

Comment: the primary problem is path file ... why? how use input stream for this?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870825/getting-the-absolute-file-path-from-content-uri-for-searched-images) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510584/onactivityresults-intent-getpath-doesnt-give-me-the-correct-filename) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer) and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). Then, delete the `FilePath` class.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is wrong to begin with.

Do not try to obtain a file system path.

You got a content uri. Use it to open an input stream. After that you can use the content as if you had opened a file input stream.

Comment: So throw away `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);`. And open an InputStream instead. `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`.