# Android - FileNotFoundException on Xiaomi (but not on my other smartphone)

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have developed a simple app:
in the main activity you can open the gallery and select multiple pictures. Their URIs will be stored in a list, and then in another activity I get the URIs from that list to make some thumbnails of these pictures.

The code I use for those two actions are the following.

On the main activity I get the Uri and convert it into a String:

```
Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

// Get the cursor
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
uriStringList.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
cursor.close();
```

On the second activity I get the Uri in this way:

```
uriList.add(Uri.parse( "file://" + uriStringList.get(id)));
iwt.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(uriList.get(id), 100, 100));
```

Everything works smoothly on my Android 5.1 (API 22) smartphone, but when I run the app on my newest Xiaomi smartphone with MIUI 9.2 (Android 7.1.2 API 25), I get a java.IO FileNotFoundException.

Does anybody know the reason of this error?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510756/115145), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871320/115145), and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Anyway, I am already using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer), and it actually works on one of my smartphones, but not on the other one. I edited the original post, including the code when I use decodeSampledBitmapFromUri.

Comment: "I am already using a method described here" -- that statement does not line up with the code in your question. The code in your question assumes that everything is a file (hence the `"file://" +`). As [I pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer), few `Uri` values point to files on the filesystem.

Comment: Actually, if I do not put the "file://" + I get the same FileNotFoundException on both phones.

Comment: Perhaps you should be holding onto the full `Uri`. My guess is that you are calling `getPath()` on `mImageUri` somewhere along the line, before the data gets into `uriStringList`.

Comment: In the main activity I convert `Uri` values into `String` values, because it is the only way I found to send them to the second activity through an intent (`putStringArrayListExtra`). Then in the second activity I convert them back into `Uri` values.

Comment: "In the main activity I convert Uri values into String values" -- and how are you doing that? "because it is the only way I found to send them to the second activity through an intent" -- a `Uri` is `Parcelable`, and so you can put them in an `Intent` extra. However, [your permission to use the content identified by the `Uri` values is limited to the initial activity, by default](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), and so you will have some more work to do.

Comment: I edited the post adding the code I use to convert Uro into String. I know Uri is Parcelable, but I have a List of `Uri`s, and I have not found a way to send a list of Uri to another activity.

Comment: To convert a `Uri` to a string, call `toString()`. To convert the string representation back to a `Uri`, call `Uri.parse()`, without any concatenation stuff. To pass an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects in an `Intent` extra, use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` on `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried with `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`, avoiding all the conversions, and now it works! Your advices were really helpful :)

Comment: Trying again my app I noticed that without the cursor, the multiple images I select in the gallery are added to the list regardless of the "pick order". But I cannot get an Uri from the cursor, I can use just `cursor.getString(columnIndex)`

Comment: There is no guarantee of any "pick order".