# Filechooser selecting a word file downloaded from GMail crashes app

Tags: android-studio, gmail, android-afilechooser

I am using a file chooser to pick a WORD file downloaded from GMail, it causes the app crashed.Here's my code segment:

== file chooser code ==

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//sets the select file to all types of files
String [] mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/msword",    
"application/vnd.openxmlformats 
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select   
File"), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

== onActivityResult ==

```
Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
String selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(getActivity(),  
selectedFileUri);
```

== FilePath.getPath() ==

```
...
// DownloadsProvider

final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
final Uri contentUri = 
ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads
/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
```

== getDataColumn() ==

```
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
     String selection, String[]    selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The **selectedFilePath** has this value: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/164, the **contentUri** in FilePath.getPath() also has this value. When it goes in getDataColumn() method, the cursor is null after executing "query()".

Tried those: 1) If I put the same WORD file direct to the "Download" folder and pick it from "Downloads" link from the file chooser, I have no issue. It seems that somehow going through GMail and downloading from GMail causes problem. 2) File still downloaded from GMail and in Download folder, if I pick it through Internal storage->Download (i.e, absolute path), it works since the code goes through different flow (which is not shown above).

I am wondering where I missed in the code to handle the file downloaded from GMail?

Thanks in advance!

The Phone is Galaxy S9, android 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and experiment, it ends up retrieving file name and content from InputStream instead of trying to get the path of the file. Here's the code segment:

1) get file details:

```
Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
FileDetail fileDetail = FilePath.getFileDetailFromUri(getActivity(), selectedFileUri);
String fileName = fileDetail.getFileName();
int fileSize = (int)fileDetail.getFileSize();
```

Here's the FileDetail.java:

```
public class FileDetail {
    // fileSize.
    public String fileName;
    // fileSize in bytes.
    public long fileSize;

    public FileDetail() {

    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(long fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }
}
```

In FilePath.java:

```
public static FileDetail getFileDetailFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        FileDetail fileDetail = null;
        if (uri != null) {
            fileDetail = new FileDetail();
            // File Scheme.
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                fileDetail.setFileName(file.getName());
                fileDetail.setFileSize(file.length());
            }
            // Content Scheme.
            else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                Cursor returnCursor =
                        context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (returnCursor != null && returnCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                    fileDetail.setFileName(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
                    fileDetail.setFileSize(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex));
                    returnCursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return fileDetail;
    }
```

2) get the file content:

```
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(selectedFileUri);
 byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileSize];
 is.read(fileContent);
```

I found those codes from internet and didn't keep track of where they are. With Filename & filesize in FileDetail.java and the file content in "filecontent" byte arrays, I have all information I need now.

Comment: How about SD Card, dropbox and google drive? Have you tested it?

Comment: @HB, I didn't test for those. I tested only for selecting a file from Downloads link and absolute path in file browser.

Comment: If you want, you can have a look at a library I've created, it handles all local URI's as well as Google Drive, Dropbox and OneDrive. I've also added a demo app to test - https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT