# How to get real folder name after select Directory in Android

Tags: android, file

I'm writeing an XML file in android and I want to let the user select a folder, in the local storage( or SD card)

So i'm using this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

everything work quite well, 
on "onActivityResult" method i'm getting this to get the folder choosed by the user:

```
final String path = data.getDataString();
```

but I get this:

> *content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads*

And when I continue and try to write I get this error:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

> content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/ATMob_Export_2019-06-03_16-29-01.zip

I suppose that I'll receive something like :

> */storage/emulated/0/download*

Any idea ?

Best Regards

Comment: Reading material: [Universal way to write to external SD card on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40068984/295004)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510584/onactivityresults-intent-getpath-doesnt-give-me-the-correct-filename and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870825/getting-the-absolute-file-path-from-content-uri-for-searched-images