# intent.getData() returns wrong file Uri

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Other apps can use my activity to open `.zip` files.

```
    <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/zip"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

But sometimes when I try to open file with my activity, `intent.getData()` returns wrong uri!
For example the file actual path is `storage/emulated/0/abc.zip` but `intent.getData().getPath()` returns `/external/file/749`.

The code I use:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if(data != null){
        Log.d("TAG", "MAIN: " + data.toString());
        Log.d("TAG", "MAIN: " + data.getEncodedPath());
        Log.d("TAG", "MAIN: " + data.getPath());
        //All returns something like /external/file/749
    }
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456406/1911941

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48510584/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221312/115145