# Unable to get the correct file path in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the file path of a file from a file picker.

My problem is, that when I output the file path in text form, I get the following output:

`file:/`storage/emulated/~rest_of_path~

I assume, to access the file, the path should begin something like this:

`file:///`storage/emulated/~rest_of_path~

or at least `file://`

Why do I only get `file:/` i.e a single slash.

The code in charge for getting the file path:

```
    ...
File fileToImport = new File(actualfilepath);

                    String tempPath =  uri.getPath();
                    if (tempPath.contains("//")){
                        tempPath = tempPath.substring(tempPath.indexOf("//")+1);
                    }
                    if ( actualfilepath.equals("") || actualfilepath.equals(" ")) {
                        fileToImport = new File(tempPath);
                    }else {
                        fileToImport = new File("file://"+actualfilepath);
                    }


                    // TODO: 2019-06-04
                    functionforfile(fileToImport)
                    filePath.setText(fileToImport.toString());
```

The text view for the code `filePath.setText(fileToImport.toString());`

shows me the file path *for debug purpose only*

if `fileToImport = new File("file://"+actualfilepath);` has `File("file://"actualfilepath)` instead, it outputs the file path without `file://` which I understand, but why do the two `//` get removed when I add `"file://" + actualfilepath`

How could I add the correct `file:///`

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am trying to get the file path of a file from a file picker" -- if by "file picker", you mean `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, those are not "file" pickers, and you are not getting files. If by "file picker" you mean a file-picker library, bear in mind that Android Q and R are eliminating access to external storage, so you should consider switching to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and working with the `content:` `Uri` values it gives you.

Comment: ok, I use ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: I suggest that you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer. If the scheme of your `Uri` is `file`, then you already have a `file` `Uri` and do not need to do anything further. If the scheme of your `Uri` is `content`, it does not necessarily point to a file on the filesystem that you can access. Just use the `content` `Uri`, via `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile`.