# Uri lacks 'file' scheme while converting Uri to File

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

Primarily, I want to clarify that this isn't a duplicate. I've gone through every question on Stack Overflow that has a similar topic but couldn't find a solution. I've also gone through the documentation, which doesn't specifically mention this issue.

I'm trying to convert a Uri to a File using `.toFile()` in Kotlin; however, it throws an error that says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Asample.txt
         at androidx.core.net.UriKt.toFile(Uri.kt:43)
```

I've accessed the file through the file picker, and I've also requested `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Although the file can be picked, it throws the error I mentioned above. The code for accessing the file looks like this:

```
 val activityResultLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            val file = uri?.toFile()
            if (file != null) {
                Log.d("data file", file.readText())
            }
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: "I'm trying to convert a Uri to a File" - this is not, and never has been, a valid thing to do as has been covered many times over. Use the APIs for accessing the contents of the Uri directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone is still stuck with the same problem, you can try this code:

```
 val activityResultLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            val file = createTempFile()
            uri?.let { context.contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }.use { input ->
                file.outputStream().use { output ->
                    input?.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
            Log.d("txt content", file.readText())
            file.delete()
        }
```

For more context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221353/22091687