# I'm received the output path that i can't access because It's custom content provider on android

Tags: java, android, image-capture, securityexception

I'm received the output path(EXTRA_OUTPUT)  that i can't access because It's custom content provider on android.

My app is supporting the IMAGE_CAPTURE for other apps.
but my app isn't works when I received the capture intent by the chrome browser.
I had debugging and I found the invalid URI from intent by the Chrome browser. 
It's URI of custom content provider that I don't have access permission.

I have to compress my bitmap to output path(EXTRA_OUTPUT) for retrun the result.
but If i access the uri. my app occurs the SecurityException.
How can i write capure bitmap to this uri ?

The chrome browser is sent me the uri for custom content provider.

> Bundle[{output=content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/1460353414880661298992.jpg}]

ex content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/14603482183391770716616.jpg

if i'm try to get the file path to call the query `'context.getContentResolver().query(receiverURI)'`,
 It throw SecurityException.

It's same when to open outputStream
`context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)`;

```
java.lang.SecurityException:
Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.CompatibilityFileProvider
```

How i can write my bitmap 
to the output uri the received by chrome browser app ?

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Chrome. If they gave you the `Uri`, they need to include the flags to allow you to consume the content.