# Permission Denial while reading content Uri of chrome images through openInputStream()

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, inputstream, android-contentresolver

I am trying to share images from chrome browser to my application using implicit intent ACTION_SEND.

While sharing searched images, app receives intent with a Content URI like this: content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1457448067808912906311.jpg

Using **ContentResolver** and **openInputStream()** to read in bytes associated with the content Uri, it crashes app throwing Security Exception : Permission Denial

Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.CompatibilityFileProvider from ProcessRecord{e2de807 31401:com.theteamie.android.app/u0a784} (pid=31401, uid=10784) that is not exported from uid 10060
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3576)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4799)
   at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1466)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1087)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:942)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
   at com.theteamie.android.app.activity.PostShareActivity.copyToLocalFile(PostShareActivity.java:141)
   at com.theteamie.android.app.activity.PostShareActivity.processChosenFile(PostShareActivity.java:103)
   at com.theteamie.android.app.activity.PostShareActivity.onCreate(PostShareActivity.java:72)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

It used to be working few days back when I coded this functionality.I got help from answers to my this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870825/getting-the-absolute-file-path-from-content-uri-for-searched-images).Can someone please suggest what could be causing this issue now?

Comment: "It used to be working few days back" -- just to confirm, you are using the `Uri` when you receive it, right? If you have saved this `Uri` somewhere (e.g., database) and are trying to use it later, then this behavior is expected.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Uri which I recieve from intent.Not saving it anywhere and using it later.

Comment: Off the cuff, it feels like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Oh okay. Hoping that fix is done soon :(

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are trying to fetch the image from same activity for which you set ACTION_SEND in Android Manifest. Its most probable reason for above issue