# Failed in converting File path to byte array android

Tags: android, arrays, file, file-manager

I'm trying to convert a File to byte array format. The selected actual path is there in the storage, but still its throwing exception as "**File Not Found**". Can anyone help me to sort out this?

Thanks for your precious time!..

**calling file manager**

```
btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

        }
    });
```

**getting response**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 switch (requestCode) {
        case 7:

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
        System.out.println("====== path :   "+filePath);

        File file = new File(filePath);
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
            fis.close();

            System.out.println("====== bytesArray    "+bytesArray);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("====== File Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("====== Error Reading The File. IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870825/getting-the-absolute-file-path-from-content-uri-for-searched-images). You are not working with files. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Do not attempt to use `getPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following grade **its Apache commons gradle**

```
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

then use this code

```
    byteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
```

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion, when Im trying to run the application, showing error as        

    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: still its throwing "File not Found".  but my file path location shows like /document/primary:file/myDoc_4.pdf.