# Android Open Failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to implement a text file picker and then put its content in an edittext, but when I try to get the file I get this error: Open Failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

**MANIFEST**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Asking for permissions**

```
    public void configurar(){
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        {
            if (checkPermission())
            {
                // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                // Your Permission granted already .Do next code
            } else {
                requestPermission(); // Code for permission
            }
        }
  }

   private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 12);
    }
}
```

**Calling the File Picker**

```
   public void carregarArquivo(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent()
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione arquivo"), Aplicacao.FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

**Getting the callback**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Aplicacao.FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            if(data != null){

                Uri arquivoSelecionado = data.getData();
                File arquivo = new File(arquivoSelecionado.getPath());
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();
                mConteudo.setText(text);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            mConteudo.setText(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Additional info
I'm running it on Android 5.0.1 API 21

***Screenshots when I was debugging***

**So it openned this screen where I can choose the file to select**

[image]

**Then, after selecting that file....**
  [image]

**Now the error**
  [image]

The error is at this line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
```

Does some know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/35870825/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221312/115145. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not a file picker, in that it does not pick files and you do not get filesystem paths back.

Comment: Changes and now working 

InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(arquivoSelecionado);

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));